# Fixed navbar Issue

Tags: css

Guys I am having a tough time trying to fix this navbar at top. Please help...need it fast

```
<nav>

    <span class="nav-btn"></span>

    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

the style i have put is:-

```
 nav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}


nav .nav {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav li{
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav li a{
    color: #fff;
    padding: 25px 35px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #333;
    display: block;
}

.nav li a:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
}
```

even after

```
nav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I am unable to get it fixed.

Comment: you want the nav to remain at the top always even if scrolled?

Comment: It is already fixed, I don't see any issue. Just add some content so that scroll appears in body to see that it is fixed.

Comment: Maybe should delete the question?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fixed already.. what is the trouble you have with this???

```css
body{height:1000px;}
nav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}


nav .nav {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav li{
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav li a{
    color: #fff;
    padding: 25px 35px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #333;
    display: block;
}

.nav li a:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
}
```

```html
<nav>

    <span class="nav-btn"></span>

    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```